# Как записать в переменную результат полученный из запроса в базу данных?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Я делаю запрос `String SQL_SUM_FILES_SIZE_IN_STORAGE = "SELECT SUM(SIZE_FILE) FROM FILE_ JOIN STORAGE_ ON FILE_.STORAGE_ID_F = STORAGE_.STORAGE_ID WHERE STORAGE_.STORAGE_ID = :idParam";` в базу данных, использую базу `Oracle`, получаю сумму всех значений находящихся в столбце `SIZE_FILE`. 
Пробую сделать таким образом:

```
public Integer sumSizeFilesInStorage(Long idStorage){
    Integer amount;

    try (Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()){
        NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(SQL_SUM_FILES_SIZE_IN_STORAGE);
        query.setParameter("idParam", idStorage);
        amount = (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:503)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:592)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:56)
    at dz_spring_3.dao.FileDAO.sumSizeFilesInStorage(FileDAO.java:122)
    at dz_spring_3.Demo.main(Demo.java:11)
```

Если так пытаюсь сделать `amount = (Long) query.uniqueResult();` , то падает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at dz_spring_3.dao.FileDAO.sumSizeFilesInStorage(FileDAO.java:123)
    at dz_spring_3.Demo.main(Demo.java:11)
```

А я что-то не могу додуматься как привести к нужному типу ((

Подскажите как полученную из запроса сумму присвоить переменной `Integer amount` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown
>   parameter position: 1

Именованные параметры не поддерживаются JPA в нативных запросах, только для JPQL.

Используйте позиционный параметр:

```
String SQL_SUM_FILES_SIZE_IN_STORAGE = "SELECT SUM(SIZE_FILE) FROM FILE_ JOIN STORAGE_ ON FILE_.STORAGE_ID_F = STORAGE_.STORAGE_ID WHERE STORAGE_.STORAGE_ID = ?1";
query.setParameter(1, idStorage);
```

---

Вы не можете преобразовавать объект кастом, который не является суперклассом:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Преобразуйте используя класс [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
amount = ((BigDecimal)query.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

Comment: Roman C, спасибо за помощь в очередной раз ))