# Не передаются параметры метода репозитория в запрос @Query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, repository

**В чем проблема:** Есть следующий репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface StoriesGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<StoriesGroup, Long> {

    @Query(
        value = "SELECT * FROM stories_group " +
                "JOIN group_browsing_history " +
                  "ON group_browsing_history.group_id = stories_group.stories_group_id " +
                "JOIN customers " +
                  "ON customers.customer_id = group_browsing_history.customer_id " +
                "where stories_group.is_active = :isActive and customers.external_id = :externalId",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    public List<StoriesGroup> getWatchedStoriesBy(@Param("isActive") boolean isActive,
                                                  @Param("externalId") String externalId);
}
```

Метод getWatchedStoriesBy возвращает пустой список при абсолютно любых параметрах, даже в тех случаях, когда для указанных параметров есть данные в БД.

**Мои настройки (файл application.properties):**

```
logging.config=classpath:log/logback.xml

server.port=8080
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Stories
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=my_password;
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Как я пытался решить проблему:**

1. сперва я протестировал сам запрос в БД через pgAdmin. Запрос корректно отрабатывал для всех тестовых данных.
2. Далее я проверил код, который вызывает getWatchedStoriesBy - во всех случаях код корректно
   передавал параметры этому методу.
3. Потом я попробовал убрать параметры у метода getWatchedStoriesBy, а вместо :isActive и
   :externalId  подставил конкретные значения для которых есть данные в БД. И метод корректно отработал.
4. Затем я вернул параметры на место и проверил как выглядит sql запрос переданный Hibernet (установив spring.jpa.show-sql=true) и увидел следующее

   ```
   SELECT * FROM stories_group 
     JOIN group_browsing_history
       ON group_browsing_history.group_id = stories_group.stories_group_id 
     JOIN customers 
       ON customers.customer_id = group_browsing_history.customer_id 
     where stories_group.is_active = ? and customers.external_id = ?
   ```

и если я правильно понимаю, то знаки вопроса показывают, что значение параметров отмеченных @Param не передалось методу. А почему - не имею ни малейшего понятия. При всем при этом не возникает никаких исключений.

**Вопрос:** почему параметры метода getWatchedStoriesBy не попадают в итоговый sql запрос? Как это починить?

Comment: а какие типы данных у полей is_active и external_id? ну и по возможности - скопируйте сюда строку `where`, которая получилась в результате `вместо :isActive и :externalId подставил конкретные значения для которых есть данные в БД`

Comment: У isActive тип boolean, у externalId тип String. Строка where выглядела так

Comment: Какое исключение возникает?

Comment: where stories_group.is_active = 3 and customers.external_id = 'qwe-2748494'

Comment: @Roman - никаких исключений не возникает. Метод просто всегда возвращает пустой список.

Comment: Попробуй позиционные параметры. Как то [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/887062/204920).

Comment: @Roman, уже пробовал - результат тот же.

Comment: И уберите `@Param` аннотации они там ни к чему.

Comment: Вы не ответили про типы данных полей в БД. Именно в БД. Eсли у вас с `is_active = 3` работает, то в этом часть проблемы - это поле явно не bool в БД.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, извините, это была опечатка. Строка должна выглядеть так: where stories_group.is_active = true and customers.external_id = 'qwe-2748494'. Типы в БД следующие: у колонки is_active тип boolean, у колонки external_id тип character varying (255)

Comment: RomanC, когда я использовал позиционные параметры, то @Param убирал.